# What setting should I configure to move new site folder?

Tags: paths

I have a live site and a new wordpress site.

The new wordpress site is ready to replace the live site.

I want to move the new site folder /public_html/wordpressnewsite to /public_html/

but I afraid the path image url can't change from

http://example.com/wordpressnewsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/jj11.jpg

to

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/jj11.jpg

What is the correct way to move the site?

What setting should I configure to move new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need any and all references in the database to the old folder to be changed -- this would be not just images but any internal links as well. If you'd rather not dive into the .sql file yourself, the easiest thing is probably to use a plugin like Velvet Blues ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ ). It will change all the old urls to the new ones.

This is what you're wanting, correct?

If there are any hardcoded paths in your template files (hopefully not!) you'll have to change those manually. Velvet Blues just addresses the database.